# shipping label printing for fedex

Tags: php, fedex

I am working on shipping label printing for fedex.

Information is given below in an array. All values are showing in generated label 
but Adress, Delivery address, company name are not shown. Sample array is given below.
please suggest why we are not able to get all the values. also suggest any possible
related resources to solve this problem.

```
$fed = new FedExDC('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx');

$ship_data = array(    
4=>    'power act Soln' //STORE_NAME
,5=>    '312 stuart st'     //MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_ADDRESS_1
,6=>    '180 richfield drive' //  MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_ADDRESS_2
,7=>    'Boston'              //  MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_CITY
,8=>    'MA'             //MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_STATE
,9=>    '02134'         //MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_POSTAL
,11=>  'Power act'               //delivery_company
,12=>   'Jay Powers'            // recipient's contact name
,13=>   '183 richfield drive'    //delivery_street_address
,14=>   'street'    //delivery_street_address2
,15=>   'Sanjose'       //delivery_city
,16=>   'CA'                // delivery state
,17=>   '92315'          // delivery_postcode
,18=>   '6173335555'     // To phone number
,23=>   '1'             // payment type (1 is bill to sender)
,25 => '1' // reference number
,38 => 'package department' // department name
,50=>   'US'             // delivery country
,57 => 10 // "your package" height dimension
,58 => 10 // "your package" width dimension
,59 => 10 // "your package length dimension
,68 =>  'USD'               //DEFAULT_CURRENCY
,75=>   'LBS'               //MODULE_SHIPPING_FEDEX_EXPRESS_WEIGHT
,116 => 1                           //package_num
,117=>  'US'             // sender's country
,183=>  '6175556985'        //from ph no
,440 =>'Y'                 //home delivery 
,1266 =>'N'                 //saturday delivery   
,1273=> '01'             // packaging_type
,1274=> '01'             //service_type
,1333=> '1'                     // drop off type (1 is regular pickup)
,1368 => 2                  // label type (2 is standard)
,1369 => 1              // printer type (1 is laser)
,1370 => 5                  // label media (5 is plain paper)
,1401=> '1.0'           // total weight
,3001 => 66666              // purchase order number
,3002 => 123456                 // invoice number
);
```

Comment: Why do you need the company name, address, etc. sent back? Aren't you collecting that data and sending it to FedEx in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read your question it seems like the shippinglabel-solution already exists and works, and that the only issue is that there is data missing.

The software you use for printing (Some webapplication where the code you are posting is used..?) probably has a `template` for the shipping label. This template is usually in the form of a `report`. See if you can somehow `edit` this template. Somebody might have deleted the `labels` which contain address and companyname.